# create a triangle to keep the inner content from overflowing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a triangle which should keep the inner content from over-flowing when making the inner content draggable.

I have tried different things like polygon and canvas but each and everything doesn't seem to work or maybe I am not going into the right direction.

Is there any jquery plugin or library to help me with this?

[image: Triangle with background]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please give us your code so we can help you with your problem.

Comment: Need to be responsive?

Comment: @Kharchi No need to be responsive

Comment: @SZenC I tried doing a conversion to canvas and clipping the image but I can't put the canvas's layer with z-index above the icons because it would remove the surrounding text

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ -> maybe this is what you want....it can't get outside the parent

Comment: @HellBaby that's simple UI which wouldn't help me what I want all the icons to be draggable at once not just one or two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used some html to make content draggable and stylable :D
The added an canvas on the bottom with a triangle:
 here link : http://jsfiddle.net/hyxmvn2h/1/
Some code to allow the answer :p

```
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      parent = $('#canvas').parent('.triangle'),
      pw = parent.outerWidth(),
      ph = parent.outerHeight();

   canvas.width = pw;
   canvas.height = ph;

  if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pw/2,0);
    ctx.lineTo(pw,ph);
    ctx.lineTo(0,ph);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

draw();
```

Dragging kind of algorithm is inside the fiddle
Why do you need to hide when dragged out? Just make sure that the elements is dropped inside triangle rows...
NB: not responsive as asked

Comment: the example in jsfiddle is not draggable and what I want is to hide anything that goes outside that triangle whenever you drag the inner content to left, right, up or bottom. - Thanks

Comment: I thinks that it can be hardly done... sorry i cant help you D: im not that good with js

Comment: Thanks - I am grateful to you for wanting to help me